# Image upload script not working correctly

Tags: php, html, mysql, image, uploading

Hello I need a bit of help with uploading images to my website, I have changed this script around a few times but I just cannot get it to function correctly?

When I attempt to upload any images, the script seems to fail and no records are updated as well as no images are uploaded? Have I done something wrong with the script?

```
if(isset($_POST['uploadimage'])){
    $user = $_POST['user'];
    $target_dir = "userimg/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]);
$uploadOk = 1;
$imageFileType = pathinfo($target_file,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
// Check if image file is a actual image or fake image

 $check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]);
  if($check !== false) {
        $uploadOk = 1;
  } else {
      $imgerror = 1;
        $uploadOk = 0;
  }

// Check if file already exists
if (file_exists($target_file)) {
    $imgerror = 2;
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check file size
if ($_FILES["fileToUpload"] > 500000) {
    $imgerror = 3;
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Allow certain file formats
if($imageFileType != "jpg" && $imageFileType != "png" && $imageFileType != "jpeg"
&& $imageFileType != "gif" ) {
    $imgerror = 4;
    $uploadOk = 0;
}
// Check if $uploadOk is set to 0 by an error
if ($uploadOk == 0) {

// if everything is ok, try to upload file
} else {
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
        $filenameimg = basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]);
        mysqli_query($conn, "UPDATE friends_list SET display_img = '$filenameimg' WHERE id = '$user'");
        $imgerror = 6;
    } else {
        $imgerror = 5;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Consult these following links http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php and http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php
and apply that to your code.

Comment: Is it a good idea to use the error reporting tools even while a code is working in case something may go wrong, will users be able to view the errors that show up if I do this?

Comment: That's only to be used when testing. and yes, those will appear to the user. If you're seeing them, so will they ;-)

Comment: I will keep that in mind for the next time I get stuck, thank you very much ! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are missing a couple important pieces here, the first part that would cause an issue is your `basename` function, you are not including the filename.

`$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]);`

Should be

`$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);`

And to get the image size, you also need to use the same process:

`$check = getimagesize($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"]);`

Use this idea to alter your 'Check File Size' section too, I won't do your work for you but I will send you in the right direction.
You also need to remember to add `tmp_name` to move the uploaded file.

`if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {`

Once you have corrected these mistakes, the images should process correctly. Unless you are getting any other errors?

Comment: That's okay no worries, as @Fred -ii- pointed out above, if you are not sure where the errors are occurring you can use the error reporting functions to provide a better idea. You should also think about running a few extra checks in your code to make sure that the image cannot be uploaded to the wrong user and what to do if two users want to add two different images with the same name, which could happen. At the moment you are just denying that, but it depends on your script use really.